# Load image in QML WebEngineView using QQuickImageProvider

Tags: qt, qml, qwebengineview

I'm injecting HTML content into a QML [WebEngineView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html) using the `loadHtml` method, and I'm trying to get it to load the images through a [QQuickImageProvider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html).

Up to now, we've been successfully loading images from a Qt resource container (qrc), but this is not flexible enough.

**contentimageprovider.cpp**

```
#include "contentimageprovider.h"

#include <QDebug>

ContentImageProvider::ContentImageProvider() : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickAsyncImageProvider::Image)
{

}

QImage ContentImageProvider::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << id;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QtWebEngine/QtWebEngine>

#include "contentimageprovider.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QtWebEngine::initialize();

    engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("content-images"), new ContentImageProvider);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.4

Image {
    source: "image://content-images/this-image-is-requested";
}

WebEngineView {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        loadHtml("<img src='qrc://images/this-image-is-displayed.png' /><img src='image://content-images/this-image-should-also-be-requested' />", "/");
    }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
requestImage "this-image-is-requested"
requestImage "this-image-should-also-be-requested"
```

**Actual output**

```
requestImage "this-image-is-requested"
```

And the image loaded via qrc in the WebEngineView is displayed, and a broken image is shown for the other one.

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: "this is not flexible enough" < we don't want to have to bake-in the content and images at compile time - which is why I'm trying to use the image provider

Comment: You are mixing QML and HTML. ImageProviders could be used in QML, but they are unknown for HTML-Engine or whatever. image:// link in HTML will be understood as an URL-Handler(like mailto:, sendto:, tell:, skype:, etc..) in WebEngine. So if you need image: handler you need to declare&define it in WebEngine. Look at QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Xplatforms who pointed out the initial error in assuming that the Chromium engine under the QML WebEngineView would interact with the QML Quick engine and trigger the image provider.

The solution was to implement a *QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler*:

```
void ImageRequestHandler::requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *request)
{
    // request->requestUrl() is a QUrl
    QFile *image  = new QFile(QDir::currentPath() + "/storage/content/" + request->requestUrl().path() + ".png");

    // makes sure the image deletes itself when closing the file
    connect(image, &QIODevice::aboutToClose, image, &QObject::deleteLater);
    // close the file when the request job is done
    connect(request, &QObject::destroyed, image, &QIODevice::close);

    QMimeDatabase mimeDB;
    QMimeType mimeType = mimeDB.mimeTypeForFile(image->fileName());

    request->reply(mimeType.name().toUtf8(), image);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // web engine to provide content display
    QtWebEngine::initialize();

    // intercept requests from the web engine to provide locally loaded content and images
    ImageRequestHandler *imageRequestHandler = new ImageRequestHandler();
    QQuickWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->installUrlSchemeHandler("image", imageRequestHandler);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```